# inserting DataTable into psql

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, npgsql

if I use:

```
 NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from table", conn)

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
```

To get data from the server to a DataTable,

Is there a way to similarly put it back after I'm done with the data?
Like emptying the table and inserting the whole DataTable into it.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a command to drop the table (or just empty all rows if the table structure won't be modified) and iterate through the rows in your DataTable to insert the modified rows from the DataTable into the new table in your Database.